# Create javascript object from doubleqoute text

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a messy problem I'm stuck with.
I try to use my mvc model in JavaScript as object (for later knockout binding).

What I'm do is this in Controller (object is simplified for showing my problem):

```
    public ActionResult ProjectServiceOverview()
    {
        var result = new 
            {
                Text = "Hello ""Test"" test.."
            }

        return View(result);
    }
```

and this in client code (aka java script):

```
$(function () {
    var jsonModel = '@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Model))';
    var mvcModel = JSON.parse(jsonModel);

    [...]
```

My problem is that at runtime the server side generated json (var jsonModel) looks like this and this is invalid because of double quots.

```
{
    "Reason": "Hello "Test" test..."
}
```

I now try to find a solution to get this to work without doing a nasty replace ( " with \") operation. Is there a smarter way? In my working code the objects comes from a database mapped by entity framework.

**UPDATE 1**

Ok I now found out that the 'Html.Raw' call also removed the \" inside the text nodes.
I think I can handel this.

Now I'm doing a simple test like:

```
 $(function () {
    var json = '{ "Reason": "Hello \"Test\" test..."}';
    var mvcModel = JSON.parse(json);

    debugger;
```

And this also get an error because illegal signs!?

Please help :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok I don't get it to run with json.
What I'm doing now is the following.

Action Methode:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
ViewBag.JSModel = serializer.Serialize(modelObject);
```

JScript:

```
$(function () {
    var mvcModel = @(Html.Raw(ViewBag.JSModel));
```

This works for me. If somebody has a better solution, I would be happy to hear.

Greetings Steffen